# SwiftUI - How to stop ScrollView receiving taps behind other view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, touch, scrollview

I have a `LazyVStack` inside a `ScrollView` that sits below a smaller view (the yellow view in the image).

[image]

The problem is that when the grid is scrolled up, the cells can still receive taps through the yellow view which I really don't want. I want to put a search `TextField` into that view and the touches get mixed up and the user experience is a mess. In the example code I added a button to swap to a `List` to check if that had the same scrolling problem. It doesn't.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var useList = false
    @State private var gridLayout: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    
    var data = (0...249).map { "\($0)" }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TopInfoPane()
                if useList {
                    List(data, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text(item)) {
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
                            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                                NavigationLink(destination: Text(item)) {
                                    Cell(item: item)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Scroller")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { useList.toggle() }) { Text("Swap") })
        }
    }
}

struct Cell: View {
    var item: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 75)
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct TopInfoPane: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TopInfoPane")
            .frame(height: 48)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

I've tried setting animation on the view to nil and setting `.allowsHitTesting(false`) but they didn't help. I'm at a loss because I really didn't expect the `ScrollView` to scroll beyond its own frame anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clip ScrollView as follows

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: gridLayout, alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: Text(item)) {
                Cell(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.clipped()
```